# If I am eligible for employer sponsored insurance which doesn't offer coverage in my state, can I still get an APTC on the exchange?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, health-insurance, affordable-care-act

Normally if an employer offers "affordable" coverage that meets minimum standards, employees eligible to participate no longer qualify for an Advance Premium Tax Credit, even if they want to turn down the employer's plan, and buy their own plan on their state (or the federal) exchange.

Is this true even when the employer's plan doesn't include any doctors in the employee's area? For example if a NY based company offers an HMO that only includes in-state doctors on their network, can employees that commute from NJ still lose their APTC?

Comment: Just curious, how far do you actually live from the nearest covered doctor? Also, the plan at your employer that costs the LEAST amount, what percent is the total premium for 12 months of your annual income?